# Splitting a string at certain differing character counts

Tags: c#, string, count, split, stringbuilder

I have a semi-complicated file full of lines. These lines can fall under one of two formats:

- Person
- Company

The specification for a company line is like so:

- 10 Characters = company identification, record specification and status of company
- 22 Characters = Blank spaces (filler)
- 8 Characters = number of employees and length of company name
- Max of 161 characters = Company name + "<" delimiter

And the specification for a person:

- 12 Characters = Parent company number, appointment date and type
- 12 Characters = unique reference number
- 1 Character = corporate indicator
- 7 Characters = Blank spaces (filler)
- 16 Characters = confirmed appointment date and resignation date
- 8 Characters = Postcode
- 8 Characters = Date of Birth
- 4 Characters = length of variable data
- Max of 1125 characters = Variable data delimited by "<"

First, I need to test the 11 character to determine the type of string. Pseudo-code:

```
if (string.count(11) = " ")
{
    ItsACompany();
}
else
{
    ItsAPerson();
}
```

Then I need to do a custom count for every type of specification - so far, all I've found is a method to split strings every nth character, and reads to the end of the string. This is recursive and not what I need.

I need an option that allows n to change per specification, and allows me to select all characters between char n and char y. Does such a thing exist?

Comment: Substring with a bit of math

Comment: You mean something like [Get String In Between Two Others with C#](http://timtrott.co.uk/string-in-between/) ?

Comment: I think that to determine the type of string you should look at the length of the line. Unless you are certain the the 11th character contains something that differentiate the two lines. Your specs don't seem to say this.

Comment: @Mihai Similar, but based upon a character count and not tokens.

Comment: @Steve Look again. With the company record, the 11th character will fall into the "Filler" category, thus will be an empty space. The length of the lines is not a proof method, since there is the possibility of a person line being shorter than a company line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract a block of text from a string you could write an extension method like this

```
namespace StringExtension
{
    public static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static string TakeBlock(this string input, int x, int y)
        {
            if(y > input.Length) y = input.Length;
            if(x > y) x = y;
            int length = y - (x-1);
            return input.Substring(x-1, length);
        }
    }
}
```

And then you could call it from your main code with (supposing to be inside the method that extracts data for the company line)

```
string parentCompany = line.TakeBlock(1, 12);
string uniqueRef = line.TakeBlock(13,24);
```

Comment: This looks extremely promising. Would you be so kind as to explain the process that led you to this answer? I wouldn't have thought of this myself.

Comment: Well not too complex. You can read about [Extension Methods here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx), the code is just two lines to ensure that the passed parameters are inside the string length and then calc what to pass to string.Substring to obtain the block of data

Comment: Not sure that this code will cover all the cases though. For example if you pass a value of x bigger than y the result is not what do you expect

Comment: Should be fine, I won't be changing the values of X and Y once I implement them, and ideally x will never be larger than y.

Comment: I suppose that. A similar problem occurred to me. But did you look at some kind of library that could solve your problems?  The first one that comes to mind is [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.com/)